# Clean install error: from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import

I try one of the simple matplotlib demo codes after a clean install of python 3.7.3 on a clean install of windows 10 (1809):

```
c:\ pip install matplotlib
ON the python command prompt:
c:\ python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
>>> from numpy import arange, sin, pi
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'NavigationToolbar2TkAgg' from 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py)
```

I read all articles google was presenting to this well known error. I tried so far to

- update pip to version 19.1.1
- uninstall matplotlib and reinstall (with or without cache)
- checked MS Visual C++ redistributable (all there)
  None of the install commands reported any error. 
  None of the remediations described in the articles solved the issue

I have no clue what to do next

Comment: while you're open to trying different options, how about installing the Anaconda distribution as a clean install? matplotlib and other scientific libraries come packaged with the distribution. Be sure to uninstall Python and any previous packages to avoid conflicts, before doing this.

Comment: tried native python from phython.org as well as Anaconda. As this is a fresh windows10 install (no upgrade) all is clean

Comment: aparently, the problem is that most examples use NavigationToolbar2TkAgg whereas NavigationToolbar2Tk seems to be the right call. At least, removing "Agg" seems to resolve the issue- meaning, the examples need a review ...